# Mysql foreign key

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I want to make a link between a table customer and a table product by an IdProduct.

Example:

```
Create table customer(
idcustomer  INT not null,
name        Varchar(20),
idproduct   INT,
);

create table Product(
idproduct INT not null,
nameProduct varchar(40)
);
```

How can I link the two together like the foreign key system for, when I select a customer, I can get all his products? It's a question about the structure of the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mysql a foreign key is a special type of constraint.  It is preferably created with the table, but can also be added afterwards.  In this case, you might define the constraint as:

ALTER TABLE customer
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (idproduct)
    REFERENCES Product (idproduct);

(Note that you have to use the InnoDB engine to take advantage of FK's in mysql.  More [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

However FK's aren't required to make a JOIN, which is how you would link the tables in a SELECT -

```
select c.idcustomer, c.name, p.nameproduct
from customer c
join Product p on p.idproduct=c.idproduct;
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to introduce a 3rd table to resolve the many-to-many relationship between customers and products. It should consist of `idcustomer` and `idproduct`.

[image]

Then, to get all the products for a given customer:

```
SELECT c.name, p.nameProduct
    FROM Customer c
        INNER JOIN CustomerProductXref cpx
            ON c.idcustomer = cpx.idcustomer
        INNER JOIN product p
            ON cpx.idproduct = p.idproduct
    WHERE c.idcustomer = 12345
```

Comment: i know that, it's just a pure example. I just want to join the table, when i select a customer, i can take his products.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you'd make a foreign key constraint (ignoring the cardinality issues that Joe rightly suggests):

```
CREATE table Product(
    idproduct INT not null,
    nameProduct varchar(40),
    PRIMARY KEY (idproduct )
);  

CREATE table customer(
    idcustomer  INT not null,
    name        Varchar(20),
    idproduct   INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (idproduct) REFERENCES Product(idproduct )
);
```

Get your data like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Product AS P
INNER JOIN Customer AS C ON C.idproduct = P.idproduct
WHERE C.idcustomer = 1
```

Comment: and when i example do a select : Select nameProduct from Product, Customer WHERE idcustomer = 1 AND  product.idproduct = customer.idproduct 
it will work??